# table=None but the table really exist

Tags: python

Python returns none but the table really exists. I inspected the website n saw the table tag.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url='https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/historical-data/'
r=requests.get(url)
url=r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(url,'html.parser')

tab=soup.find("table",{"class":"table"})
print(tab)
```

Comment: Maybe the table is dynamically inserted into the html document?

Answer (score 0):

The table does exist, but it's not of class `table`. Simply removing the parameter `{"class":"table"}` will allow you the print the table.

```
tab=soup.find("table")
print(tab)
```

Note that there can be multiple tables on the webpage, you can also use `soup.find_all`.

```
for table in soup.find_all("table"):
   print(table)
```

As it appears that the Historic Daily Table is rendered dynamically, you may want to use frameworks like Selenium to access the table. But it would be much easier to process the data fetched directly from their [API](https://web-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/ohlcv/historical?convert=USD&slug=bitcoin&time_end=1606262400&time_start=1603324800).

Comment: thx. yes as there r multiple tables..I cannot get the table I want...i.e. the historical daily table...I used soup.find_all already..I can get other tables but cannot get the historical daily table

Comment: @button It appears that this table is renderred dynamically, but I found the [URL](https://web-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/ohlcv/historical?convert=USD&slug=bitcoin&time_end=1606262400&time_start=1603324800) for an API to fetch the data directly, where `time_end` and `time_start` represent the start and end time. You can retrieve the data more directly by making a GET request to this API.

Comment: thx. Your API works. I only found the official API but the free version doesnt provide historical data. https://coinmarketcap.com/api/pricing/
Your API is good. Thx a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. Would you mind accepting the answer? Thanks.